# PDF parser text contains

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pdfbox

I want to verify PDF Document using TestNG and PDFBox.

I would ask, is PDF able to check contains text like this:

```
PDFParser parser =  new PDFParser(stream);
parser.getDocument().conntains("ABC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
  public void ReadPDF() throws Exception {
    URL TestURL = new URL("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");

    BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL.openStream());
    PDFParser TestPDF = new PDFParser(TestFile);
    TestPDF.parse();
    String TestText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF.getPDDocument());

    Assert.assertTrue(TestText.contains("Open the setting.xml, you can see it is like this"));

    }
```

Download libraries :- https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html